# How do I grep a string from files created within the last 5 hours?

Tags: grep

I have a directory that is populated every 30 mins with a text file, each day I need to grep the line with "Quality data" on it but I only want to grep from the 10 most recent files.  How can I tell grep to only look in files created within the last 5 hours?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find` to return only the files created in the last 5 hours and use its `exec` function to grep from them:

```
find [PATH_OF_DIRECTORY] -type f -cmin -300 -exec grep "Quality data" {} \;
```

where `-cmin -300` means "*created in the last 300 minutes (5h)*"